# Apache2 always loads default site as my PrestaShop front page

Tags: ubuntu, https, apache2, prestashop, default

So I have looked up a lot of forums about this topic but no one has the same problem.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 Server with a Virtual Host where I have installed my PrestaShop store. My shop domain is the Server IP address. When I try to reach my front page with the server address I always get the default Ubuntu page "It works". I can only reach my front page when I type in the Server address and behind `/index.php`. SSL is also already installed. I have also made a DNS record, a redirect with my provider domain to the server IP. My goal is to reach directly to the HTTPS front page with the domain. Now I only reach the Ubuntu default page when I type in my domain.
I activated friendly URL and now I can't even reach the front page (index.php) but all other sites from the shop are active and function properly.

I hope someone can help me and i'm sorry for my bad English.
If you need any more information please contact me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If Prestashop files are indeed in the server root and the index.php is showing Ubuntu info then rename it and copy instead the index.php form the Prestashop archive.

My guess is that somehow you kept the default index.php instead of the Prestashop's one.